# Wordpress Elementor Custom Query: how to use the post IDs from a first query into a second query in order to filter desired results?

Tags: php, wordpress, elementor

I would like to merge two custom queries into one function: The first query returns all post IDs from a custom post type (first_custom-post-type) using a meta-query (first-custom-post-type-featured = 1). Then, a second query uses the returned IDs in an array from the first query into a second query from a another relational post type (second_custom-post-type)

```
function my_query_by_post_type( $query ) {
//first query - all featured posts from
$first_meta_query = $query->get( 'meta_query' );
    if ( ! $meta_query ) {
        $meta_query = [];
    }

    $meta_query[] = [
        'key' => 'first-custom-post-type-featured',
        'value' => 1,
        'compare' => '=',
    ];
    $query->set( 'post_type', ''first-custom-post-type' );
    $query->set( 'meta_query', $meta_query );

//second query
$second_meta_query = $query->get( 'meta_query' );
    if ( ! $meta_query ) {
        $meta_query = [];
    }

    $meta_query[] = [
        'key' => 'relational_fiedl',
        'value' => $first_meta_query[],
        'compare' => 'LIKE',
    ];
    $query->set( 'post_type', ''second-custom-post-type1' );
    $query->set( 'meta_query', $meta_query );
        $query->set('post__in', $firstquery);

}



add_action( 'elementor/query/{$query_id}', 'my_query_by_post_types' );
```

Comment: `$query->set('post__in', $firstquery);` - what is `$firstquery` supposed to be here, that variable doesn't exist in the function. And if that was meant to be `$first_meta_query` - no, you can not just use a meta query object with the `post__in` operator. You will need to fetch the IDs from your first query into an array first, so that you can pass that.